# Write into another file after end of file is in buffer

Tags: java, file, eof

I am trying to write into two files.I am able to write into one file but after inserting end of file at the end of first file ,i am not able to write into other file. Program terminate without taking any input for next file.
Please tell me how to remove end of file character from buffer. 
So that the statement input.hasNext() in addRecordToTransactionFile() dont read eof character their.

```
public class TestClass {
    public static BufferedWriter mainFile;
    public static BufferedWriter transactionFile;
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void openFile() {
        // Code to open file
    }

    public static void addRecordToMainFile() {
        try{
            System.out.println("\t\tEnter data to Master File");
            System.out.printf(" %s %s %s%n? ","Master file account number" , "Name" ,"Balance");
            while(input.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    mainFile.write(String.format("%-10d %-12s %.2f" , input.nextInt() , input.next() ,input.nextDouble()));
                } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
                    System.err.println("Please Enter a valid input.%nTry Again");
                    input.nextLine();
                } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
                    System.err.println("Please Enter a valid input.%nTry Again");
                    input.nextLine();
                }
                System.out.print("? ");
            }

        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("File is Closed... Closing Application");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        input.nextLine();
    }


    public static void addRecordToTransactionFile() {
        try {
            System.out.println("\n\t\tEnter data to the Transaction File");
            System.out.printf("%s\t%s%n?" ,"Transaction file account number" ,"Transaction amount" );
            while(input.hasNext()) {
                try{
                    transactionFile.write(String.format("%-10d %.2d" , input.nextInt(),input.nextDouble()));

                }catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
                    System.err.println("Enter a valid input %nPlease try again");
                    input.nextLine();
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("File is Closed... Closing Application");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void closeFile() {
        //Code to close file
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        openFile();
        addRecordToMainFile();
        addRecordToTransactionFile();
        closeFile();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
        Enter data to Master File
 Master file account number Name Balance
? 100 Alan_Jones 232.32
? ^D

        Enter data to the Transaction File
Transaction file account number Transaction amount
?
Process finished with exit code 0
```

This program is not taking any input after inserting eof character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once `stdin` is closed (by entering `^D` from the keyboard), it will never produce any more input. So, `input.hasNext()` in your `addRecordToMainFile` method will run until `stdin` is exhausted. When `addRecordToTransactionFile` runs, `stdin` is *still closed and will produce no more input*, so that method skips the `while` loop completely.

To get a single input to write to multiple output files, I'd recommend one of either of the two following options:

- Use a token at for each input record to indicate the type of the transaction (where it should go). For example:

`M 100 Alan_Jones 232.32 (goes to main file)
T 100 Alan_Jones 232.32 (goes to transaction file)`

- Use a delimiter between each *section* of the input file. For example:

`MAIN
100 Alan_Jones 232.32
100 Alan_Jones 232.32
100 Alan_Jones 232.32
100 Alan_Jones 232.32 (all these go into the main file)
TRANSACTION
100 Alan_Jones 232.32
100 Alan_Jones 232.32
100 Alan_Jones 232.32
100 Alan_Jones 232.32 (all these go into the transaction file)`

Your input-reading logic must become more complicated in order to handle the input. Note that the second option is very similar to the scheme you already tried, except that the "end of file" character (`^D`) has been replaced by a different marker in the file that isn't "special" to the UNIX stream system: the string "TRANSACTION".

But you cannot read from `stdin` after the stream has been closed, so looking for `^D` / waiting for `input.hasNext` to return `false` will not work.